# Obfuscate/deobfuscate data in ruby and mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby, encryption, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I would want to obfuscate data when reading from mysql database using mysql. 
I want to be able to deobfuscate the data then in ruby to get back the original string.

Eg. Value for one of the fields lets say name in mysql database is  = 'Hello World'

I want to do something like :

obfuscated_name = select obfuscate(name) from users where id = 1;
obfuscated_name = 'pcdbdygcljidr2h5o8boWame'
And then use this obfuscated_name in ruby and deobfuscate it

SomeClass.deobfuscate(obfuscated_name) => 'Hello World'

Whats the easiest and simplest way to do this so that same logic is applied in mysql as well ruby.

Answer (score 2):

You can use symmetric key encryption. Put the key in a config file and then use it to encrypt/decrypt the data in question.